# Simultaneous gRPC clients sync/async server

Tags: rpc, grpc

I'm just curious,

1. Does a sync gRPC server supports connection from multiples clients?
2. If not, and the async ones does?
3. And combination of async server/sync client? is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, synchronous gRPC supports multiple connected clients out of the box. I have personally tested with up to 2000 simultaneously connected clients to an microservice written in Go exposing a single API.

Comment: out of curiosity, how do configure the grpc to work in a sync way?