# gRPC cpp async server vs sync server

Tags: c++, asynchronous, grpc

Surely a silly question. 
I don't get the differences between sync and async server.

In gRPC example on [github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld)

The distinction in async and sync isn't obvious.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486733/simultaneous-grpc-clients-sync-async-server) and with my test sync gRPC server can hanndle parallele request.

And in the asynchronous example the `server.Run();` is blocking.

So What's the difference between both ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/DuBDpK96B14)

In short,

> The async model give the application code full control over threading. Sync can handle multiple requests in parallel, yes, but they are serviced from a gRPC thread pool.
>   If you want finer control over threading, then async is the better model to use

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you got it. [This](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp.html) link will provide more details about the async basics of gRPC C++. You are right in thinking that the async model provides more finer control.

To provide a slight implementation detail - Both the async and sync models of gRPC C++ end up using completion queues. The difference is that, for the sync case, the completion queue handling is hidden from the application, while in the async case, the application has complete control over how and when the completion queues are run.